# Auto increment the column value by 1 conditionally in select query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dml

I am having input table like below:

[image]

and **in a select query** without alteration of table need an output like:

[image]

Comment: Should count for `4` be 3?

Comment: Did you try anything? If so, please show us your attempt.

Comment: Post text not images.  You lost an answer from me.

Answer (score 4):

```
drop table if exists T;
create table T(id int, nm nvarchar(10)) 
GO
insert T(id, nm) values (1,'r'),(2,'r'),(3,null),(4,'r')
SELECT * FROM T
GO
-- solution:
select 
    id, nm, 
    CASE WHEN nm is not null then count(nm) over (order by id) ELSE NULL END
from T
GO
```

compare execution plan of all solutions (using SQL 2017) :-)

My solution 21%; LukStorms solution 38%; Ian-Fogelman solution 41%

Choose your solution after you test in your specific server!
[image]

Comment: _Choose your solution after you test in your specific server!_ LOL I like it ;)

Comment: It's important point @Sami, since best solution in one system can be the worse option in another system. There are lot of parameters related to choosing best solution. but using the information we have in the question here, I would choose my solution :-)

Comment: +1  A clever way that uses the fact that a count on value doesn't count the null's. And since that doesn't require a partition then that's probably why it's faster.

Comment: A good solution, but given the volume of data, I wouldn't focus on the performance comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate a row_number partitioned on whether "nm" is null, then only show the calculated row_number when "nm" is not null.

Example snippet:

```
declare @T table (id int identity(1,1) primary key, nm varchar(8));
insert into @T (nm) values ('R'),('R'),(null),('R');

select *, 
 iif(nm is null,null,row_number() over (partition by iif(nm is null,1,0) order by id)) as [Count]
from @T
order by id
```

Comment: Are you sure.  Looks like count would start over.

Comment: It works.   Interesting use of `partition by iif(`.   I wasn't aware of that functionality.

Comment: Well, you could use a CASE WHEN instead of the IIF.  But IIF is shorter.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean the `iif()` I meant the `partition by 1 or 0`.   It seems counter-intuitive that partitioning by 1 means the row does not get counted, but 0 means it does.   But it does return the desired result for some reason.

Comment: @LukStorms Agreed :)

Comment: @paparazzo The count does start over, on what's partitioned on.  Which is a 1 or 0 in this case. So it continues for those that have the nm filled in.

Comment: And does that match the desired output from the OP?

Comment: Ok, never mind, I see now.   The outer iif() is what prevents the row_number from being counted, the inner iif() could have had the 1,0 in either order.   Got it.

Comment: @paparazzo the count doesn't "start over", at least not the way I think you mean it.  The partitioning creates two separate row counts.   One for those that have `nm` and one for those that don't.   The counts don't start over like a gaps-and-islands solution, they continue to climb.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT ID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY ID) AS [COUNT] 
    FROM [TABLE] WHERE NM IS NOT NULL 
)
SELECT S.ID,
       S.NM,
       CTE.[COUNT] 
FROM [TABLE] AS S LEFT JOIN CTE AS CTE ON S.ID = CTE.ID
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a CTE that adds a ROW_NUMBER() column and filters out rows WHERE 'nm' IS NULL.

Then SELECT from your table and OUTER JOIN to the CTE, using the ROW_NUMBER column to populate your `Count` column.